# Only show images/attachments within the gallery?

Tags: wordpress

When i create a page, add a gallery, and browse this gallery on the front-end it will browse all the attachments that are associated with that page, instead of just the images within that gallery. Is there a way to filter all the other attachments and only show the images within a certain gallery? So that, for instance, when I delete the gallery and add a new gallery on the same page > only the new gallery is shown?

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi RobbertT. Can you please let me know what you've tried and the code you're using. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the most elegant way, but i've found it very usefull.

Passing a post ID to the function below will load a gallery from the post_content of that post. So you would create a gallery and insert it into your post content, then in the template you run this function and will be returned with an array of attachments in that gallery which you are free to to whatever with, i.e slideshows and the likes.

```
function wp_load_gallery($post_id) {
  $post = get_post( $post_id );
  $regx = '/' . get_shortcode_regex() . '/';
  preg_match( $regx, $post->post_content, $matches );
  $ids = shortcode_parse_atts( $matches[3] );

  $gallery = array( );
  foreach( explode( ',', $ids['ids'] ) as $id ) {
    if($id) {
      $gallery[] = get_post( $id );
    }
  } 

  return $gallery;
}
```

Note that the shortcode is not cut from the content, so when you display the content you should run it through the strip_shortcodes function, i.e:

```
echo strip_shortcodes( get_the_content() );
```

This allows you to update the gallery whenever you want with whatever you want.

EDIT:

To simply display all images:

```
$gallery = wp_load_gallery($YOUR_POST_ID);
foreach($gallery as $image) {
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks alot. I am trying  to understand your code. To be clear; i should create a post, add a media gallery and put the postid in the `$ids['ids']` of the created post right? How should i echo/display the obtained elements? Because the code (if used right) is not displaying anything.

Comment: create a post, then insert a gallery to it by creating one in the "Add media" interface. Once the gallery is added you should get a big box in the content and if you hover over it you can see the delete and edit buttons. the function does not output anything, it only returns the attachment objects which allows you to manipulate size and the likes before displaying the gallery. I updated my answer with code showing how to display the results.